# Condensing multiple ORs in a Linq Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have this code:

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x[0] > .0005 || x[1] > .0005 || x[2] > .0005).ToList();
```

There has to be a way to just do this over an enumerable range?

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
myList = myList.EnumerableRange(0, x.Count).Where(i => x[i] > .0005)
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing/Is there a better way?

Comment: Firstly, your example goes from 1 to 3 but your Range goes from 0 to 2?

Comment: @NetMage my mistake. just fixed it in the above code.

Comment: BTW, I think you mean `myList = myList.Where(x => x[0] > .0005 || x[1] > .0005 || x[2] > .0005).ToList();`. The way you have it, you can't compile it look at the repeated `x =>` part

Comment: @Vikhram Just fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the LINQ method `Any` for that.

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x.Any(d => d > .0005)).ToList();
```

I am assuming you are looking to check all the items in `x`. Otherwise you will have to use the LINQ extensions `Take` and `Skip` to get a slice of the array. Also assuming that `x` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. Note that, if you expect `x` to be `null` you will have to handle it

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You still need to do the or equivalent - multiple `Where` clauses are effectively ANDed together:

```
yList = myList.Where(x => Enumerable.range(0, x.Count).Any(i => x[i] > .0005)).ToList();
```